# Convert Javascript/Json Date String to Java Date using Gson

Tags: javascript, json, gson

I have a date object from javascript that is converted into a string in the format like this

```
2014-05-22T15:27:49.125Z
```

Now in my java file, i am using Gson and create my builder like so

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ").create();
```

To convert the date from the string value into a Date object, i am using this.

```
Date myDate = gson.fromJson(options.getString("dateAsString"), Date.class);
```

This seems to report this error?

```
05-22 16:29:19.484: W/System.err(24636): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: 2014-05-22T15:27:49.125Z
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is with date format then try any one:

```
SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",Locale.US);
```

OR

```
SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
```